# I am using angularJS-transtale and i want to change the values in configuration part

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I have built a small application to switch languages

I create a controller where I get the value from `ng-model` and then assign the value to a variable. I need help to pass this value in `app.config`.

#### Code:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['pascalprecht.translate']);
var name = 'Anuj';
app.controller("translateController", ["$scope", "$translate", function($scope, $translate) {

  $scope.changeValue = function() {
    name = $scope.textname;
    $translateProvider.translations('en', en_translations);
  }
  $scope.changeLanguage = function(lang) {
    $translate.use(lang);
  }

}]);
app.config(["$translateProvider", function($translateProvider) {

  var en_translations = {
    "language": name,
    "greeting": "Welcome Dinesh"
  }

  var sp_translations = {
    "language": "Selected Language Spanish",
    "greeting": "Bienvenida Dinesh"
  }

  $translateProvider.translations('en', en_translations);

  $translateProvider.translations('sp', sp_translations);

  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');

}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.8" data-semver="1.3.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-translate@*" data-semver="2.5.0" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-translate/bower-angular-translate/2.5.0/angular-translate.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="translateController">
    <h1>Demo for angularJS translator</h1>
    <input type="text" name="" ng-model="textname" /> {{textname}}
    <button ng-click="changeValue()">Change</button>
    <div>
      <button ng-click="changeLanguage('en')">English</button>
      <button ng-click="changeLanguage('sp')">Spanish</button>
    </div>

    <h2>{{'language' | translate}}</h2>

    Hello!!!

    <p>{{'greeting' | translate}}</p>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

You can see code in [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Cgza8yHDfN89GKDiJqCn?p=info)

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide the code of your tries? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, How much research effort is expected https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users and How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: @fool-dev sorry for taking time in editing